# Run Java Program in Terminal from Sublime Text 3 [Mac OS]

Tags: java, macos, sublimetext3, build-system

What build system in Sublime Text 3 would you have to use to run java programs in the given Mac terminal (the one that appears when you use Spotlight, shell is called bash I think.)? Below is the code I am currently using, I have tried a bunch of changes, but I can only get the terminal to open up, however the results and the whole java program is still being run inside of the given Sublime Text console. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\" && open -a Terminal.app"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java",
    "shell" : true
}
```